# How to maintain a constant scope in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular service that fetch contacts data from the database, I then use these data so that the user can add one contact or more to a deal, so there is a many to many relationship between the deal and contact, the selected data are displayed in a grid (syncfusion grid).

I need to have a constant list of the data retrieved from database, and a varible containing the selected contacts that I pass to the syncfusion grid, when the user add from the dropdown I add this contact to the grid and remove it from the dropdown list, and if I deleted it from the grid I return it back to the drop down list, so here's my code:
this service get the contact list:

```
var contactsListDB = [];
contactService.getAll().then(function (contacts) {
    contactsListDB = contacts.data;
    $scope.contactsList = contactsListDB; // the scope used in the select input in the HTML
});
```

the method that add contact:

```
$scope.addContact = function (contact) {
    var contactJson = JSON.parse(contact);
    $scope.dealContacts.push(contactJson);

    var index = $scope.contactsList.findIndex(x => x.id == contactJson.id);
    SyncFusionDealContact($scope.dealContacts);
    $scope.contactsList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

this function is invoked in HTML:

```
<ng-form name="ContactForm">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>{{"Contact" | translate}}</label>
        <md-select ng-model="contact">
            <md-option value="{{null}}">-- {{"selectContact" | translate}} --</md-option>
            <md-option ng-repeat="contact in contactsList" value="{{contact}}">{{contact.name}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="!ContactForm.$valid" ng-click="addContact(contact)" aria-label="submit">{{'add' | translate}}</button>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <div id="GridDealContacts">
        <script id="columnTemplateContacts" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs contactDelete" data-id="{{:id}}" ng-click="DeleteContact{{:id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></a>
            <!--add delete button-->
        </script>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

When the page is loaded I check if the object is being edited and then I exclude the existing contacts from the list comming from contacts table:

```
    $scope.dealContacts = deal.contacts;

    SyncFusionDealContact($scope.dealContacts);
    execludeContacts()
```

`execludeContacts` function:

```
function execludeContacts() {
        var exIds = [];
        if ($scope.dealContacts.length > 0) {
            exIds = $scope.dealContacts.map(x=> x.id)
        }
        var conts = contactsListDB;
        conts.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (exIds.includes(item.id)) {
                conts.splice(index, 1);
            }
        })


        $scope.contactsList = conts;
    }
```

this function handles delete action:

```
$scope.DeleteContact = function (id, index) {
    if (id <= 0) {
        $scope.dealContacts.splice(index, 1)
        SyncFusionDealContact($scope.dealContacts);
    }
    else {
        if (confirm("Are You Sure?")) {

            dealService.deleteContact(id, $routeParams.id).then(function (success) {
                if (success.data.isSuccess) {
                    SyncFusionDealContact($scope.dealContacts);
                    var one = contactsListDB.filter(x => x.id == id)[0];
                    $scope.contactsList.push(one);
                    $scope.dealContacts.splice(index, 1);

                }
                else {
                    alert('Cannot delete');
                }
                SyncFusionDealContact($scope.dealContacts);

            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I tried to save a copy of the contacts list in a variable that can't be changed `contactsListDB`, so that when a record is deleted from the grid I can get it back from this array to add it in the drop-down list again, but what happens is that the array is changed:

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're asking, but I think you want to 'save' the data somewhere? If that's the case, take a look at using a factory or service. I prefer using a factory because of its simplicity.

From the short period I've worked with Angular, I know that a factory will always stay alive (even while switching views in SPA) until you refresh the page.

In a simple example, the factory will hold a list of the contacts, and have several functions like your addContact and deleteContact. This makes your code less cluttered and you just have to call the factory and its functions in your code.

I currently can't give a specific example (as I prefer using my own factories and its usage), but [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/) you can find a comparison between factory and service and how to use them.

If I misunderstood your question, please do tell. :D